# How is the best aproach to upgrade jhipster 5.8 to 6.9.1 version?

Tags: jhipster

i have worked on a monolitic project using jhipster 5.8.2 and in the las week we need to upgrade current project to 6.9.1 version, i have tried to use "jhipster upgrade" folowing this article: https://www.jhipster.tech/upgrading-an-application/
But this steps removed all files... Could you help me?

Comment: Int he linked doc, there are 2 options, which one did you use?  If you used option 1, you should rather open an issue on github, run the upgrade using "--debug" flag and paste the output.

Comment: yes, i'm using the first jhipster upgrade